# How to implement animation of liking and disliking such as Tinder app on button click?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I am using [Swipecards](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) this project as a reference to implement card swipe functionality. I am happy with with swipe functionality but I want two different buttons for *Like* and *Dislike* functionality: I want to do some animation such as swipe left and right.

Here is my adapter; I pass my button to Adapter through constructor. Now can you please tell me how can I manage click event to remove card using animation?

```
public abstract class CardStackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context mContext;

/**
 * Lock used to modify the content of {@link #mData}. Any write operation
 * performed on the deque should be synchronized on this lock.
 */
private final Object mLock = new Object();
private ArrayList<CardModel> mData;

public CardStackAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mData = new ArrayList<CardModel>();
}

public CardStackAdapter(Context context, Collection<? extends CardModel> items) {
    mContext = context;
    mData = new ArrayList<CardModel>(items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    FrameLayout wrapper = (FrameLayout) convertView;
    FrameLayout innerWrapper;
    View cardView;
    View convertedCardView;
    if (wrapper == null)
    {
        wrapper = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_bg);
        if (shouldFillCardBackground())
        {
            innerWrapper = new FrameLayout(mContext);
            innerWrapper.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.card_bg));
            wrapper.addView(innerWrapper);
        }
        else
        {
            innerWrapper = wrapper;
        }
        cardView = getCardView(position, getCardModel(position), null, parent);
        innerWrapper.addView(cardView);
    }
    else
    {
        if (shouldFillCardBackground())
        {
            innerWrapper = (FrameLayout) wrapper.getChildAt(0);
        }
        else
        {
            innerWrapper = wrapper;
        }
        cardView = innerWrapper.getChildAt(0);
        convertedCardView = getCardView(position, getCardModel(position), cardView, parent);
        if (convertedCardView != cardView)
        {
            wrapper.removeView(cardView);
            wrapper.addView(convertedCardView);
        }
    }

    return wrapper;
}

protected abstract View getCardView(int position, CardModel model, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

public boolean shouldFillCardBackground()
{
    return true;
}

public void add(CardModel item)
{
    synchronized (mLock)
    {
        mData.add(item);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

protected void removeItem(int position)
{
    mData.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public CardModel pop()
{
    CardModel model;
    synchronized (mLock)
    {
        model = mData.remove(mData.size() - 1);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return model;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return getCardModel(position);
}

public CardModel getCardModel(int position)
{
    synchronized (mLock)
    {
        return mData.get(mData.size() - 1 - position);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public Context getContext()
{
    return mContext;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I posted code and please help me.